# Is proper morphism from affine scheme affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm reading Mumford-Oda's lecture notes http://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/624_08/mumford-oda_chap1-6.pdf. And they use the fact:"Let $f:U \to Y$ be a proper morphism of noetherian schemes and $U$ is affine, then $f$ is affine" to prove Chow's lemma(p.73). In the errata they say that there was assumed in this chapter that scheme $Y$ is separated over $\mathbb Z$, in these assumptions the fact is true and I'm able to prove it(even if $f$ is not proper). But I don't know is this fact true if $Y$ is not separated.

Comment: The question in the body of the post is missing something from the title. Do you wish to assume $U$ is affine or not? Because without this assumption it's definitely not true, witnessed by e.g. $\mathbf{P}_\mathbf{Z}^1\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Oh, sorry. Yes, $U$ is affine. I'll correct it.

Comment: This follows from the 'cancellation theorem'. Namely, since affineness is closed under base change and composition, to check that $f:U\to Y$ is affine (thinking about it as a comm. triangle over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$), it suffices to check that $U\to\mathbb{Z}$, and $\Delta:Y\to Y\times_\mathbb{Z} Y$ are affine. The former is obviously true, and the latter because $Y$ is separated, and so the diagonal is a closed embedding.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, I wrote that I'm able to prove it in the case of separated $Y$. My question is about non-separated $Y$ and proper $f$.

Comment: No, it is not true in general when Y is not separated.  A sufficient condition on $f$ would be finiteness.